# Operations on nearest indices numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

An example of my numpy array `scores` and its `m` number of nearest neighbors;

```
scores = np.random.normal(-0.2,0.01,1000)
m = np.int(np.sqrt(scores.shape[0])+0.5)
```

I want to compare the `i`th value in `scores` with its `m` nearest neighbors (index-wise). The comparison should be done by something similar to

```
x[i] = (scores[i]-np.mean(scores[m])) / np.sum(scores[m])
```

, where `np.mean(scores[m]),np.sum[scores[m]]` represents the mean and sum of the `m` nearest neighbors of `scores`. If it can handle the first and last `m` indices, that's a bonus. With `x` as a numpy array I should be able to use something similar to

```
scores[x > threshold]
```

to get all scores that exceeds a certain threshold. The idea is to call `scores[i]` an outlier if it exceeds this particular threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve it using [scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html):

`uniform_filter` is equivalent to [Box blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur) (1 dimensional box filter in your case).

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

#scores = np.random.normal(-0.2,0.01,1000)
scores = np.array(np.r_[1:30]).astype(float) # Initialize to values 1 to 30 (for testing)
m = np.int(np.sqrt(scores.shape[0])+0.5) # m = 5

mean_scores = scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter(scores, size=m, mode='reflect', cval=0.0)
sum_scores = mean_scores * m

x = (scores - mean_scores / sum_scores)
```